# Open a slidedown() dependant on where the hash tag in the link is on the target page

Tags: jquery, html

Ok so here's the problem, this is a little hairy so I'll try to break it down as much as possible:

I have a link:

```
http://www.example.com/stuff.html#tag
```

Now that link leads to a page with multiple divs that are hidden and expand when clicked. I know I say it's slideDown() in the title, but it's not really. The code I'm using was a fix for a bug I was encountering with the slideDown, it would hiccup and jerk about 10 px up after the animation completed, this is what the code I have looks like:

This is the .js

```
var $div = $('#option1');
var height = $div.height();
$div.hide().css({ height : 0 });

$('.xpand').click(function () {
  if ( $div.is(':visible') ) {
    $div.animate({ height: 0 }, { duration: 200, complete: function () {
        $div.hide();
      } 
    });
  } else {
    $div.show().animate({ height : height }, { duration: 200 });
  }

  return false;
});
```

and the html

```
<div class="topic xpand">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="example.html" />
  </div>
  <a href=""><div class="plus_sign"></div></a>
  <div class="context">
    <p><a href="">Title</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="option1"><p style="margin:0px">
    <p>
      <a name="tag"></a>CONTENT GOES HERE
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now what I need to do is have the relevant section expand based on which #tag is appended to the link and hopefully also have the page center on it as well.

I've been bashing my head against the wall for a while now and all  I've got so far is this:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
      var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); 
      alert("Hash test, current hash is: " + hash);
      // traverse the dom and find div to expand
      // activate code to slide content down
      // move the window to the anchor tag location
  } else {
        alert ("no hash");
      // No hash found
  }
```

Am I even going about this in the right way?

Any input even pointing me in a better direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Be defensive with `window.location.hash`. Some browsers/versions return a string complete with the leading `#`, and some don't.

Comment: So are you just trying to use the bottom snippet of code to get the value after the hash, which you want to use in place of your hardcoded selector in the first snippet? Where the value after the hash is the id of the div you want to expand? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: The only tricky thing I see here is ensuring that all images are loaded before opening the appropriate section. Either use a `window.onload` handler (or the jQuery equivalent) or make sure every image has height and width set (in HTML or CSS). Otherwise you are likely to the sort of jump that you describe in the introduction.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot thanks for the tip about the #, and the info about the load issue, I'll keep them in mind

Comment: @idor_brad That's pretty much it, except the hash is supposed to be inside one of the the expandable divs, so I have to find a way to locate which div the hash is in, then have that div opened and then have the page scroll to the hash, all right when the page is loading. I hope I'm explaining that right, I'm not a big jQuery guy so it's proving harder than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is excellent at dom traversal. Given the value of `hash` that you are taking out of the URL, you can simply select the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) div matching a selector and slide that down.

```
$('a[name=' + hash + ']').closest('div').slideDown();
```

If you are trying to slide down that div with the wrapper class you could use `.closest('.wrapper')` instead.